500 error when trying to browse a link
Receiving the following error when trying to browse for a link in Message templates:
Exception:
Failed to start application

  at /var/www/joomla/libraries/src/Factory.php:158
  at Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()
     (/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php:203)
  at authenticate_joomla()
     (/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php:73)
  at checkAuthentication()
     (/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php:212)
  at require('/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php')
     (/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/core/bootstrap.php:39)
  at require('/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/core/bootstrap.php')
     (/var/www/joomla/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php:15)           

How can i resolve?




I'd try to replace line 203 in ../civicrm.php as "JFactory::" is deprecated in Joomla 5 and must be replaced. I raised an issue 6 days ago. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/55

this is in joomla 4

made changes per your proposed change, and Factory could no longer be found

Please change the file administrator/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php and use the following code for the function authenticate_joomla near the end of the file (line 193 f.) to the following:
function authenticate_joomla($config) {

  $joomlaBase = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))))));

  define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
  define('JPATH_BASE', $joomlaBase);
  define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

if (version_compare(JVERSION, '4.0.0', 'lt')) {
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
    $mainframe->initialise();
    
    $user_id = JFactory::getUser()->id;
  } 
  else {
    $container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

    $container->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

    $app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication::class);
    
    $user_id = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getUser()->id;
  }

  if (JFactory::getUser()->id == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

I tested this successfully.

We have to avoid using JFactory::getApplication('administrator') as since Joomla 4 'getApplication' no longer takes arguments. From the J4 potential backward compatibility page, https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4

I will test this first chance I get

could you test this already?

Have you tried using CKeditor5 or summernote as a replacement got Kcfinder?

Ckeditor is fine, but you lose the ability to browse for links
